# Mazur's theorem-abelian group of rational points of an elliptic curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

From Mazur's theorem we have the following:

If $E |_{\mathbb{Q}}: y^2=x^3+ax+b, a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ an elliptic curve, then $$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \text{ for } n=1, 2, \dots ,10, 12$$ 
or $$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2m\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z}, \text{ for } m=1, 2, 3, 4$$

A special case is the following:

$$E|_{\mathbb{Q}}, y^2=x^3+ax, a \in \mathbb{Z}$$ We suppose that $a$ is not divisible by $4^{th}$power $\neq 1$. Then $$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}} \cong \left\{\begin{matrix}
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} & \text{ if } -a=\square \\ 
\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} & \text{ if } a=4\\ 
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} & \text{ otherwise }
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Could you explain it to me??

Comment: What needs explaining? This just says what the torsion group of an elliptic curve can be.

Comment: Why is the torsion group isomorphic with these at each case?? And why do we take these cases?? I haven't understood it... @rfauffar

Comment: The Mordell-Weil Theorem says that the group of rational points on an elliptic curve is finitely generated, and so is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^r\oplus T$ where $T$ is a finite abelian group. One could wonder if all finite abelian groups appear as the torsion group of an elliptic curve, but Mazur's Theorem says exactly which ones appear.

Comment: The proof of Mazur’s Theorem is not basic or elementary in any sense, and when it first appeared, it was considered a notable triumph. The special case you mention at the end may not be too hard to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your question is about the special case of Mazur's theorem for the curves $y^2=x^3+ax$, as the proof of the full theorem is much involved.

Anyway, you could look at Silverman's The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, GTM 106, pages 310+311 for an idea how to prove this.