# $[2]Q=P$ with the rational coordinate of $Q$ in an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let
$$\tag{1} y^2=x^3+Ax+B $$
be an elliptic curve, $A, B$ are integers and $P$ is a point on the curve with rational coordinates. Is there always a point $Q$ such that $[2]Q=P$ such that the $x$-coordinate of $Q$ is rational?

The formula we get form doubling points, tells us coordinates of $Q$ depends on $a$ and the coordinates of $P$, if we put those values in the formula, we get the value of x coordinate of $Q$, and thus get $y$ coordinate of $Q$ from equation $(1)$,  **, we see from the forumula given below in image, x coordinate of $Q$ is always rational (Given that the x-coordinate of $P$ and $a$ are rational)**, is it correct? am I missing something ?

[image]
Here, $f(x)=y^2.$

Comment: There is always a point $Q$ such that $[2] Q = P$ as you say, but it is not necessarily true that $Q$ has rational coordinates.

Comment: @user45878 the x coordinate of $Q$ is rational, the y coordinate might not be, right?

Comment: I don't see why that would be true. In general, the $x$ coordinate of $Q$ can be obtained by solving a degree $4$ equation in the $x$ coordinate of $P$ with coefficients depending on $A$ and $B$, (See page 54 of Silverman, for example).

Comment: @user45878 I have attached an image, note that if $X, a$ are rational  then the formula of doubling point gives us a rational x-coordinate of $Q$, because the slope $\lambda$, even if it is not a rational becomes rational by squaring it, note $\lambda$  becomes irrational because of $Y$, if $\lambda$  is irrational then there is a chance of getting irrational x-coordinate of $Q$, please check.

For the formula, see page 10 of :http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/Galperin.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-2x$. Then, one can easily show that $E(\mathbb{Q})\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so that the only points on $E$ with rational coordinates are the point $\mathcal{O}$ at infinity and $P=(0,0)$. If there was a point $Q$ with rational coordinates such that $2Q=P$, then $4Q = 2(2Q)=2P=\mathcal{O}$, so the order of $Q$ would be $4$. However, that would imply a few contradictions (with the size of $E(\mathbb{Q})$, with the isomorphism type of the torsion subgroup, etc), so it is impossible, and no such point $Q$ can exist.

Edit to add: the $x$-coordinates of the points of order $4$ on $E$ are given by the quotient of the $4$-division polynomial, by the $2$-division polynomial, which is
$$(x^2 - 4x + 2)(x^2 + 2)(x^2 + 4x + 2),$$
and all three irreducible polynomial divisors over $\mathbb{Q}$ are of degree $2$, so no point $Q$ of order $4$ has an $x$-coordinate that is rational.

Comment: In this post only the $x$ coordinate has to be rational, $y$ might be irrational, I am not sure Mazur's theorem (where both $x, y$ are rational) agrees with this condition, also plz see this post,according to which $x$ is rational point on elliptic curve: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580905/determining-rational-number

Comment: @Andrew I've added an explanation that no point of order $4$ in this case has a rational $x$-coordinate.

Comment: Hello, I am thinking about the above problem again, if I try to check in an algorithmic way, whether a point $P$ with a rational $x$ coordinate exists or not, when $x$ coordinate of $Q,$ and coefficient $ A, B$ are given, it should be easy, but I couldn't find the algorithm, could you please hint me how should I try? Thank you.

Comment: @ConsiderNon-TrivialCases you can simply check if $x^3+Ax+B$ is a square in the rationals.

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to know the percentage of such $P$ that will have an elliptic curve and a point $Q$ on the curve as described in the post? So, we can say, for example, at-least $20 \%$ out of all pairs of rational number have an elliptic curve such that $P=[n]Q, n\geq2$ (note it could be part of infinite order, I don't mean torsion-group points only).

Answer (score 3):

For an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $E_{\text{tor}}(\mathbb{Q})$ can be $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$(see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122047/mazurs-theorem-abelian-group-of-rational-points-of-an-elliptic-curve)), so $E(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}^N$. Let $P$ be $(\bar{1},0,...0)$, then there doesn't exist such a $Q\in E(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $2Q=P$.

But as you see, by solving these equations, we get these roots in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, so there does exist a point $Q\in E(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$ such that $2Q=P$.